# How to calculate this multivariate limit changing to polar coordiantes?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate the limit: $$ \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)}{\ln{\left(\frac{19x^{2} -x^{2} y^{2} + 19y^{2}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\right)}}.$$ Somebody suggested me to change to polar coordinates, so I did $$ \lim_{(r, \theta) \rightarrow (?, ?)}{\ln{\left(\frac{19r^{2} -r^{4} \cos^{2}{(\theta)} \sin^{2}{(\theta)}}{r^{2}}\right)}} = \lim_{_{(r, \theta) \rightarrow (?, ?)}}{\ln{\left(19 -r^{2} \cos^{2}{(\theta)} \sin^{2}{(\theta)}\right)}}.$$

But here is where I have the problem, since I don't know where $(r, \theta)$ tends to. I'd like to know how I can determine this. Please don't tell me the answer since I need to learn how to calculate this limit by myself. Thanks.

Comment: Ask yourself what happens to the $r$ of polar coordinates when the moving point $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$.

Comment: @coffeemath You mean, since $r = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$, to evaluate $\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}$ and then to make $r$ tend to the result of the aforementioned limit? But what happens to $\theta$? Everyone tells me it should be dropped but I don't know why.

Comment: $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ is equivalent to $r\to0$.  That's why we replace the limit by $r\to0$ when working polar coordinates.  However, as you no doubt have seen, $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ can be accomplished in several different ways (paths), which can sometimes lead to different limiting values.  When working in polar coordinates, $r\to0$ is approach along a ray to the origin.  If $\theta$ is not involved, or if its presence in the limiting expression is dominated by $r\to0$, then there is no problem.  If $\theta$ is involved, then the approach can vary depending on $\theta$, and this must be considered.

Comment: Simple examples: (1) $x^{2}+y^{2}=r^{2}\to0$ as $r\to0$ no matter what $\theta$ is; (2) $y(x^{2}+y^{2})=r^{3}\sin\theta\to0$ as $r\to0$ no matter what $\theta$ is; (3) $\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{x^{4}+3y^{4}}=\frac{r^{4}\cos^{2}\theta\sin^{2}\theta}{r^{4}(\cos^{4}\theta+3\sin^{4}\theta}=\frac{\sin^{2}(2\theta)}{4(\cos^{4}\theta+3\sin^{4}\theta)}$ which depends on $\theta$ (and indeed, the limit does not exist as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$).

Answer (score 0):

When you convert to polar coordinates, you need to eliminate $\theta$ or at least insure that the limit does not depend on $\theta$ as $r\to0$ (note that $r\to0$ implies $x^{2}+y^{2}\to0$ which implies $(x,y)\to(0,0)$; however, if $\theta$ is involved, the approach to the origin (in principle) depends on the path).  For this particular limit, we end up with
$$\ln\left(19\cos^{2}\theta+19\sin^{2}\theta-(r\cos\theta\sin\theta)^{2}\right)=\ln\left(19-\frac{r^{2}}{4}\sin(2\theta)\right)=\ln19\;\text{as}\;r\to0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$(x,y)$ could tend to $(0,0)$ through any path so, $\theta$ is arbitrary in the limiting process and needs to be taken as a general variable. This way, in polar coordinates the limit reduces to one dimension, $r \rightarrow 0$.